# Need to stop while loop after 50 loops

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a while loop to display the data in a sql table and group the data from each row within a list item. I need the loop to stop after displaying 50 rows from the sql table. If it's helpful, $id is unique and for each row.

```
    <?php
            include("db.php");
            $query="SELECT * FROM `stories`";
            $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            ?>

            <li>

            <?php
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
            $id = $data['id'];
            $img_link = $data['img_link'];
            $page_path = $data['page_path'];
            $tag_alt = $data['tag_alt'];
            $category = $data['category'];
            if(is_null($page_path)){$page_path = "#";}
            ?>

            <img alt="<?php echo $tag_alt; ?>" src="<?php echo $img_link; ?>" width="200" height="200">

            <h3><a href="#"><?php echo $title; ?></a></h3>
            <a href="categories/<?php echo $category; ?>.html"><label> </label><?php echo $category; ?></a></span>
            <p><?php echo $tag_alt; ?></p>

            </li>
                            <?php
            endwhile;
            mysqli_close($connection);
            ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you just put `LIMIT 50` in the SQL?

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM stories LIMIT 50";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first option is you can use `LIMIT 50` like this

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM `stories` LIMIT 50";
```

The second one is you can maintain a counter variable if you don't want to use LIMIT 50

```
 <?php
            $counter = 0;
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $counter+=1;
                $id = $data['id'];
                $img_link = $data['img_link'];

                 if($counter>50)
                 {
                        break;
                 }
```

Comment: It's almost always better to sort/limit the data in the query itself, so you can avoid having to do it in your PHP code. Makes your code cleaner, IMO. +1

Answer (score 2):

In the query you can give like this.

(In case of sqlserver):

```
$query="SELECT TOP 50 * FROM `stories`";
```

(In case of Mysql or postgre):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `stories` LIMIT 50 ";
```

If you want to show results 51 to 100 in next page, you should pass page number or counter to a page, as well as u should change your sql a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Is it your solution??

```
$i=1;
 while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) && $i <= 50):
{
  //Code Here
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way should be make a query with a 50 limit

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM `stories` LIMIT 50 ";
```

But if for some reason you need your array after in the same page and you only want to show in this case the first 50, you can do something like:

```
 while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array[]=$data;
 }

for($i=0;$i<=49;$i++){
    $id = $array[$i]['id'];
     //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for everyones help here. Using the LIMIT function seemed to work best. I added BETWEEN and RAND to improve functionality.

```
<?php include("db.php"); $query="SELECT * FROM `stories` WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 200 order by RAND() LIMIT 20"; $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query); ?
```

Thank you again, nothing beats the talented service  found on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM `stories`";
```

replace it with

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM `stories` LIMIT 50 ";
```

Comment: I didn't mention it in questions but I would like to display the data in 'groups of 50' rows and use some prev/next buttons to move through 50 at a time. I don't think the limit will work for that?

Comment: you need to pagging for it.

Comment: @buzrw if you want paging you need to first put the html of you paging